# Freezing the history file temporarily

Tags: zsh, command-history

These two questions address how to keep a given command from being added to the shell history:

- [Is there any way to keep a command from being added to your history?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6094/is-there-any-way-to-keep-a-command-from-being-added-to-your-history)
- [How can I run a command in zsh without pushing it onto the current session's history?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48305/how-can-i-run-a-command-in-zsh-without-pushing-it-onto-the-current-sessions-his)

The answers focus on solutions where the user **prefixes each command** (e.g. with a space). What I am looking for is a single command that I can run once, and that would effectively "*freeze*"  my history file in the shell until I unfreeze it later with another command.

While the history is "*frozen*":

1. I want my commands to be able to be able to **read** from the existing history file (e.g. so that I can do command searches e.g. `C-r`, and standard autocompletion.
2. I want to prevent any commands I run from being added to the history

How can I accomplish this with zsh?

Comment: would setting `HISTORY_IGNORE` to something like `*` be in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `fc -p` to start a new history list, and `fc -P` to recall the previous history list. After a plain `fc -p`, you get a blank history. You can pass a file name to `fc -p` to read the history from that file, so save the history and immediately read it back with `fc -p`. When you call `fc -P`, it restores the value of `HISTFILE` from before the call to `fc -p`.

```
freeze_history () {
    fc -A
    fc -p $HISTFILE
    unset HISTFILE
}
unfreeze_history () {
    fc -P
}
```

Unfortunately the history can't be edited directly in memory, you can only populate it artificially by reading from a file.

Answer (score 2):

I use following aliases in my `.zshrc`:

```
alias disablehistory="function zshaddhistory() {  return 1 }"
alias enablehistory="unset -f zshaddhistory"
```

So I can run `disablehistory` and no new command will enter history from my current session. Then, I can run `enablehistory`.

How it works? `disablehistory` defines [history hook function](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html).

> **If any of the hook functions returns status 1** (or any non-zero value other than 2, though this is not guaranteed for future versions of the shell) **the history line will not be saved**, although it lingers in the history until the next line is executed, allowing you to reuse or edit it immediately.

So it instructs `zsh` to always reject history entry.

`enablehistory` unsets (`-f` stands for function) `zshaddhistory`  function, so default behavior returns.

Answer (score 0):

These might help: 
You can type `unset HISTFILE` to turn off history for the session. Logging out and back in will start it up again.

Also, you can return to a command in history and erase it by hitting `CTRL-u`.

Good luck!

Comment: Does unsetting HISTFILE prevent reading previous commands from history?

Comment: @JeffSchaller No, it doesn't. However, `HISTFILE` only matters at the time you exit the shell or save the history explicitly. If you unset it then set it again, the history from the time it was unset is kept.